# Fill bubbles with color in svyplot() in R (survey package)

Tags: r, plot, survey

I use the very nice `survey` package to create plots of a stratified samples in R. There are different ways to create scatter-plots that represent sampling weights but I prefer the so called `Bubble plots`. `Bubble plots` are scatter-plots with circles whose area is proportional to the sampling weight.

I would like to know if I can fill the bubbles with a specified color. Setting color of the outline works as described below. However changing the type of symbol with the pch parameter fails (this would be the standard method for scatter-plots in R).

```
library("survey")
data(api)
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

# create bubble plot
svyplot(api00~api99, design=dstrat,
        basecol=function(df){c("goldenrod","tomato","sienna")[as.numeric(df$stype)]},
        style="bubble",alpha=c(0,1))

# try to set fill with pch (fails without error message)
svyplot(api00~api99, design=dstrat,
        basecol=function(df){c("goldenrod","tomato","sienna")[as.numeric(df$stype)]},
        style="bubble",alpha=c(0,1),pch=15)
```

[image: Bubble plot with custom color but without custom fill]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following:

```
getcol <- function(df) c("goldenrod","tomato","sienna")[as.numeric(df$stype)]

svyplot(api00 ~ api99,
    design = dstrat,
    basecol = getcol,
    style = "bubble",
    alpha = c(0,1),
    pch = 21,
    bg = getcol(dstrat$variables))
```

[image]

Some comments:

1. In base R's `plot`, when using `pch = 21` you can set the outline colour with `col` and fill colour with `bg`.
2. Here, `basecol` is an `svyplot`-specific argument, which internally sets the outline colour `col`.
3. We can use the same function that we used for `basecol` to fill circles with the matching colour, by recognising that `dstrat$variables` is the `data.frame` that contains column `stype`.

Comment: awesome! Thanks!!